# Common Lisp Way to Rename a Namespace

Tags: common-lisp

What is the common lisp way to rename a namespace to something else. So instead of writing hunchentoot:start I could write ht:start.

I'm looking for something like pythons import A as B.

Edit: Using the accepted answer, the code for adding a nickname for hunchentoot is as follows:

```
(rename-package :hunchentoot :hunchentoot '(:ht))
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

What you call a namespace is a Common Lisp package created with [`defpackage`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/m_defpkg.htm)

You would like the package nickname to be `ht`

Performing a `defpackage` on an existing package has implementation defined behavior, but some implementations permit adding nicknames that way.

There is also a function [`rename-package`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_rn_pkg.htm#rename-package) that renames and adds nicknames to a package.

Comment: Here's an example usage: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12719039/which-regular-expression-libraries-should-i-use-in-common-lisp?answertab=votes#tab-top

Answer (score 1):

I use this :

```
(defpackage :foo+bar
  (:use :bar)
  (:export
   #:*foo* #:foo #:foo-p #:foo-ffs!
   . #.(let (ext)
         (do-external-symbols (sym :bar)
           (push (symbol-name sym) ext))
         ext)))
```