# Which regular expression libraries should I use in Common Lisp?

Tags: regex, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn Common Lisp and want to use regular expressions for parsing a text file.  Which library is the easiest to use for a beginner like me?  Am I right in assuming it depends on which implementation of Common Lisp I'm using?  I see some promising Google results, but I thought it wouldn't hurt to see if I can get some good advice from the Lispers out there. Thanks!

Comment: General knowledge: you can find a list of recommended libraries on [cliki](http://www.cliki.net/Current%20recommended%20libraries).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the beginner just use [CL-PPCRE](http://weitz.de/cl-ppcre/). It is fast, robust and stable, and works fine on any implementation.

There's also a small trick to make working with it more pleasant - adding a nickname of `RE` besides `PPCRE`.

```
(rename-package "CL-PPCRE" "CL-PPCRE" '("PPCRE" "RE"))
```

So you'll be able to use it this way: `(re:scan ...`